# Can't find my post through facebook's search api

Tags: facebook, search, facebook-opengraph

I'm trying to find my own (public) wallpost with the facebook search API.
The message contains an unique string "50428E8C2021"

But the API call http://graph.facebook.com/search?q=50428E8C2021 has no results.

Any ideas?

**Update:**
Accessing the message http://graph.facebook.com/100002274526967_242666405819175 responds with `false`.

But when call the API with an user-accesstoken the request response with the post ("type": "status")
With "privacy":{"description":"Public","value":"EVERYONE","allow":"0","deny":"0"}

Answer (score 0):

Not all content is indexed via the search API. It only contains posts, for example, that were published in the last two weeks or so.

Comment: Searching for something popular returns very recent posts http://graph.facebook.com/search?q=ipad